# Shift focus from last cell of DataGrid to another control when user presses Tab key in Silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, datagrid

I am using Datagrid component in Silverlight application. The user navigates to Datagrid rows and column using Tab key. When the user is in last cell of Datagrid, I wan't to move the focus to a particular control outside Datagrid.

I have made use of the LostFocus event of the label control - which resides in the last cell. However, I am not able to determine which row or cell has raised the event.

Please advice, how to detect the last cell of the Datagrid either from Label event or any of Datagrid event.

Comment: The easiest way I can think to do this. Set [TabNavigation="Once"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabnavigation%28VS.95%29.aspx) on your DataGrid, and then make the control you want to have it focus immediately after the last thing in DataGrid to be the very next thing in the DOM order of your xaml so then default logical order of FocusManager will do your work for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris for helping out...I don't wish to go via XAML default flow. I have a specific control on which I need to get focus. Hence, I wanted to raise an event on last cell of Datagrid and shift the focus to required control. Also, TabIndex won't help, since there are numerous controls on the view which comes up on various conditions.

Comment: Personally I've never once had to hard set TabIndex, that's the point of good UI architecture. The visibility conditions etc are irrelevant then. Good luck though.